# Variable in isActive method in ng-class, angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a html file that is used with a directive in angular where scope.course is defined in a .js file. 
In the code below the `ng-href="courses/{{course.url}}"` works nicely and gives the link of "courses/myurl"

But when putting in a variable in the isActive method in the ng-class it doesnt show, as if I cant access it from here.

```
<li ng-class={active: isActive('/courses/{{course.url}}')}><a ng-href="courses/{{course.url}}">Overview</a></li>
```

My isActive method looks like this:

```
scope.isActive = function(route){ 
    console.log(route);
    return route === $location.path(); 
}
```

But it logs "/courses/" without the anything else

How can I put in course.url into my isActive method?

Comment: Your isActive method should return a boolean value. Can you paste your isActive method code?

Comment: My isActive method is: `scope.isActive = function(route){
             return route === $location.path();
         }`

Comment: Yes, then I believe answer posted by fikkatra should work. have you checked on your console to see if the route === $location.path() evaluates to true? You are using a strict equaltiy operator. There may be discrepancies. Just try and double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var mod = angular.module('myapp', []);
mod.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.course = {
    url: 'myurl'
  };
  
  $scope.isActive = function(route){
    return route === '/courses/myurl';
    }
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <div ng-class="{'active':  isActive('/courses/' + course.url) }"><a ng-href="courses/{{course.url}}">Overview</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still, if the method doesn't return a boolean, it won't work. ng-class works with boolean values.

Comment: I tried this line but got an error in the console: 
"angular.min.js:114 Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/ueoe?p0=%7B'active'%3A
   at Error (native)
   at http://localhost:3000/libs/angular.min.js:6:416"

Comment: you forgot the double quotes after ng-class= . Updated answer with working code snippet.